# Simplest Service Fabric Reliable Collection (Dictionary) example

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to implement **the simplest usage of an Azure's [Service Fabric Reliable Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections) --- a `Hello World` example**, as it were --- of an `I​Reliable​Dictionary`.

In [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections) an example is given. Yet this example requires a `StateManager` object, which I'm unsure how to create or even what it is. It seems an [Actor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform) is needed, and I'm looking to avoid Actors for now.

Could anyone provide an example of this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer.

The crucial point is that one **can't create reliable collections in Stateless Services**, we necessarily need to create a *Stateful Service* if we want to make use of the *Reliable Collections*.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start) I found an example of an implementation of a Reliable Dictionary. I paste the code next, which should go in the `MyStatefulService.cs` class:

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

var myDictionary = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, long>>("myDictionary");

while (true)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    using (var tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
    {
        var result = await myDictionary.TryGetValueAsync(tx, "Counter");

        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "Current Counter Value: {0}",
            result.HasValue ? result.Value.ToString() : "Value does not exist.");

        await myDictionary.AddOrUpdateAsync(tx, "Counter", 0, (key, value) => ++value);

        // If an exception is thrown before calling CommitAsync, the transaction aborts, all changes are
        // discarded, and nothing is saved to the secondary replicas.
        await tx.CommitAsync();
    }

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
}
```